# Javascript - modify css of all instances of class on hover

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add listeners to all instances of class to modify css of ALL those instance when a user hovers over any one of those instances so far. So I'm iterating over the 'slogan' node list adding the event listener to each of them but then the function to be executed also iterates over the node list to modify all of them but it works only for the first instance.

That's what I've got

```
const slogan = document.querySelectorAll(".slogan");

function sloganHoverOver(e) {
  slogan.forEach((s) => {
    s.styles.color = "red";
  });
}

slogan.forEach((s) => {
  s.addEventListener("mouseover", sloganHoverOver);
});
```

It changes the font color of only the one instance that is being hovered over. Also it throws the following error in the console:

```
TypeError: s.styles is undefined
```

Comment: Don't add repetitive event handlers - use event delegation instead. Set one licenser and effect all instances you wish in that single handler.

Comment: Why would you use JS to do this?  CSS has a `:hover` selector.  See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: @RandyCasburn didn't know about event delegation - reading on it now.

Comment: @user2740650 css :hover only affects the instance being hovered over, as far as I know.

Comment: Oh, misunderstood the question, but it would likely be better to add and remove a CSS class to each element, like `s.classList.add("hovering")` rather than manipulating styles directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use style not styles

```
s.style.color = "red";
```

Or just use css **:hover**